# display last value from gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to display the last values from 4 columns of my gridview to the labels and I'm not using footer. how can I do it? 
here's my code but it didnt work.

```
strcomm = "select DibayarPada, JumlahDiBayar, DibayarSebelum, JumlahBayaran from 

bil where NoIC='" + Session("icvalue") + "'"

    comm = New SqlCommand(strcomm, conn)

    dr = comm.ExecuteReader

    dt2.Load(dr)

    GridView5.DataSource = dt2
    GridView5.DataBind()

    dateakhirtxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)(0).ToString()
    dateakhirtxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)(0).ToString()
    totalakhirtxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)(0).ToString()
    tarikhtxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)(0).ToString()
    jumlahtxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)(0).ToString()
```

i really have no idea what to do.

Comment: Which parts its breaks?

Comment: @Avijit at the rows.count -1 part

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Avijit There is no row at position -1. but it has values. i just dont know how to display them

Comment: do recheck the count of rows ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count

Comment: actual syntax is `ds.Tables(0)(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)("colname")` to get the last row value with column name is "colname"

Comment: I have added as answer could you please accept that as an answer?

Comment: oh you choose an answer which is not correct one.

Comment: @Avijit i did use ur answer, sir. im new here. i should be more careful with the green mark button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actual syntax is ds.Tables(0)(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)("colname") to get the last row value with column name is "colname"

Answer (score -1):

```
dateakhirtxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)("colname").ToString()
totalakhirtxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)("colname").ToString()
tarikhtxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)("colname").ToString()
jumlahtxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)("colname").ToString()
```

Comment: this is not currect answer as there are no column name like "colname". It wll through an exception.